Teenage boy gets out of juvie, gets kicked out of home, "lawyer" lets him stay at his place, sleeps in pool house
In the first season a teenage boy and his brother steal a car. They get chased by the police but end up crashing. The brother of the teenage boy goes to prison because he is the adult. The teenage boy gets out of juvie because of his case worker/lawyer. He goes home with his angry mother. At his house he get into a fight with his mother's boyfriend and gets kicked out. He calls all of his friends but no one will let him stay at their house. He ends up calling the "lawyer" who then let's him stay at his house.  The "lawyer" has a wife and a teenage boy that's the same age as him.  He gets to sleep in the pool house.

Sounds like "The O.C."  That featured a protagonist who got out of juvie and went to live with his lawyer's family, though he had to sleep in the pool house.
